type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' on Flutter
welcome.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'account_page.dart'; // Import AccountPage for logged-in users
import 'account_not.dart'; // Import AccountNotPage for non-logged-in users
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:math' show cos, sqrt, asin;
import 'placedetail.dart';

class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomePageState createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {
  final Location location = Location();
  bool isLoggedIn = false; // Placeholder for user login status
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool _serviceEnabled = false;
  PermissionStatus _permissionGranted = PermissionStatus.denied;
  LocationData? _locationData;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> nearbyPlaces = []; // Placeholder for nearby places
  bool _showLocationButton = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkLoginStatus(); // Check login status when the widget initializes
  }

  void checkLoginStatus() async {
    User? user = _auth.currentUser;
    setState(() {
      isLoggedIn = user != null;
    });
  }

  void _getUserLocation() async {
    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    _fetchNearbyPlaces(_locationData!.latitude, _locationData!.longitude);
  }

  // Function to calculate the distance between two coordinates in kilometers
  double _calculateDistance(
      double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    var p = 0.017453292519943295; // Math.PI / 180
    var c = cos;
    var a = 0.5 -
        c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
        c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a)); // 2 * R; R = 6371 km
  }

  void _fetchNearbyPlaces(double? latitude, double? longitude) async {
    if (latitude == null || longitude == null) return;

    const double maxDistance = 4.0; // Maximum distance in kilometers

    // Query Firestore for nearby places
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('places')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      setState(() {
        nearbyPlaces = querySnapshot.docs
            .map((doc) {
              var data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
              var placeGeoPoint = data['selectedLocation']
                  as GeoPoint; // Assuming 'selectedLocation' is a GeoPoint
              var distance = _calculateDistance(latitude, longitude,
                  placeGeoPoint.latitude, placeGeoPoint.longitude);
              // Add the distance to the data map
              data['distance'] = distance;
              // Retrieve the image URL from the 'imageURLs' field
              data['imageURL'] = data['imageURLs']
                  [0]; // Assuming 'imageURLs' is a list of image URLs
              data['id'] = doc.id; // Add document ID to the data
              return data;
            })
            .where((data) => data != null && data['distance'] <= maxDistance)
            .toList();
        // Sort the places by distance
        nearbyPlaces.sort((a, b) => a['distance'].compareTo(b['distance']));
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // Remove back button
        title: Text('LocalGems'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Find your hidden gems',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search',
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Perform search action
                    print('Search button pressed');
                  },
                ),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Divider(),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              'Nearby Infamous Local Places',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            nearbyPlaces.isNotEmpty
                ? Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: nearbyPlaces.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        var place = nearbyPlaces[index];
                        return Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: SizedBox(
                              width: 60, // Set the fixed width for the image
                              height: 60, // Set the fixed height for the image
                              child: Image.network(
                                place['imageURL'],
                                fit: BoxFit
                                    .cover, // Ensure the image fills the container
                              ),
                            ),
                            title: Text(place['placeName']),
                            subtitle: Text(
                                '${place['address']['city']} - ${place['distance'].toStringAsFixed(2)} km from your location'),
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (_) => PlaceDetailsPage(
                                    placeId: place['id'],
                                    distance: place['distance'],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : _showLocationButton
                    ? ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _getUserLocation();
                          setState(() {
                            _showLocationButton = false;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text('Allow Location'),
                      )
                    : SizedBox(), // Placeholder to occupy the space
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            label: 'Account',
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          if (index == 1) {
            if (!isLoggedIn) {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AccountNotPage()),
              );
            } else {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AccountPage()),
              );
            }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

placedetail.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'reviewpage.dart'; // Import ReviewPage

class PlaceDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String placeId;
  final double distance; // Add this line to include the distance parameter

  PlaceDetailsPage({required this.placeId, required this.distance});

  void _showFullImageDialog(BuildContext context, String imageUrl) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Dialog(
          child: Image.network(
            imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _launchMaps(double latitude, double longitude) async {
    final url =
        'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      // Fixed the function call
      await launch(url); // Fixed the function call
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Place Details'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        future:
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('places').doc(placeId).get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data!.exists) {
            return Center(child: Text('Place not found'));
          }

          var placeData = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          List<String> imageUrls = List.from(placeData['imageURLs']);
          var placeGeoPoint = placeData['selectedLocation'] as GeoPoint;

          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  CarouselSlider(
                    items: imageUrls.map((url) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          _showFullImageDialog(context, url);
                        },
                        child: Image.network(
                          url,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 200,
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                      height: 200,
                      viewportFraction: 1.0,
                      initialPage: 0,
                      enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                      reverse: false,
                      autoPlay: false,
                      autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
                      autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                      autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                      enlargeCenterPage: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          placeData['placeName'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Implement check-in functionality
                        },
                        child: Text('Check In'),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 8),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.green),
                          SizedBox(width: 4),
                          Text(
                            '5', // Assuming this is a placeholder value
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.location_on),
                      SizedBox(width: 8),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                                '${distance.toStringAsFixed(2)} km from your location'), // Display actual distance
                            Text(placeData['address']['city']),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _launchMaps(
                              placeGeoPoint.latitude, placeGeoPoint.longitude);
                        },
                        child: Text('View on Google Maps'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.access_time),
                      SizedBox(width: 8),
                      Text('Open'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(height: 32, thickness: 1),
                  Text(
                    'Description',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Text(
                    placeData['description'],
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Text(
                    'Reviews (13)', // Assuming this is a placeholder value
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                  ReviewWidget(
                    username: 'Ismah Haziq',
                    review:
                        "It's good. Really felt it with my tongue. Rich with flavour.",
                    rating: 4.5,
                    timePosted: '2 hours ago',
                    profileImageUrl:
                        'https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp7025909.jpg', // Replace with user's profile image URL
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (_) => ReviewPage(
                                  placeId: placeData['id'],
                                  placeName: placeData['placeName'],
                                )), // Pass placeName to ReviewPage
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text('Make a review'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ReviewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String username;
  final String review;
  final double rating;
  final String timePosted;
  final String profileImageUrl;

  ReviewWidget({
    required this.username,
    required this.review,
    required this.rating,
    required this.timePosted,
    required this.profileImageUrl,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            ClipOval(
              child: Image.network(
                profileImageUrl,
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 8),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        username,
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        timePosted,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.green, size: 16),
                      SizedBox(width: 4),
                      Text(
                        rating.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 8),
        Text(review),
      ],
    );
  }
}

reviewpage.dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class ReviewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String placeName;
  final String placeId;

  ReviewPage({required this.placeName, required this.placeId});
  @override
  _ReviewPageState createState() => _ReviewPageState();
}

class _ReviewPageState extends State<ReviewPage> {
  double _rating = 0.0;
  List<File> _selectedPhotos = [];
  String userId = ''; // Define a variable to hold the user ID

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchUserId();
  }

  void fetchUserId() {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user = auth.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        userId = user.uid;
      });
    } else {
      // Handle the case where the user is not logged in
      setState(() {
        userId = 'anonymous'; // Or set a default value
      });
    }
  }

  void _getImages() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedImages = await picker.pickMultiImage(
      maxWidth: 800,
      maxHeight: 600,
      imageQuality: 85,
    );
    if (pickedImages != null) {
      setState(() {
        // Filter out duplicate images
        List<File> newImages =
            pickedImages.map((pickedImage) => File(pickedImage.path)).toList();
        newImages.removeWhere((newImage) => _selectedPhotos
            .any((selectedImage) => selectedImage.path == newImage.path));
        _selectedPhotos.addAll(newImages);
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _buildPhotoPreview(File photo) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            _showFullImageDialog(photo);
          },
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: FileImage(photo),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 4,
          right: 4,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                _selectedPhotos.remove(photo);
              });
            },
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 18,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
              child: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white, size: 25),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _showFullImageDialog(File photo) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Dialog(
          child: Image.file(photo),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //title: Text(widget.placeName),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('users')
                    .doc(userId)
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }

                  var userData = snapshot.data?.data()
                      as Map<String, dynamic>?; // Cast to Map<String, dynamic>
                  if (userData == null) {
                    // Handle the case where userData is null
                    return Text('User data not available');
                  }

                  String username = userData['username'] ?? '';
                  String profilePictureUrl =
                      userData['profile_picture_url'] ?? '';
                  bool isTrustedUser = userData['trusted_user'] ?? false;

                  return Row(
                    children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 24,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                        backgroundImage: profilePictureUrl.isNotEmpty
                            ? NetworkImage(profilePictureUrl)
                            : null,
                        child: profilePictureUrl.isEmpty
                            ? Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white)
                            : null,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            username,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          if (isTrustedUser)
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 8, vertical: 2),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.yellow[700],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.verified,
                                      color: Colors.white, size: 16),
                                  SizedBox(width: 4),
                                  Text(
                                    'User Trusted Badge',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Center(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _rating = 1.0;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.star,
                          color: _rating >= 1 ? Colors.purple : Colors.grey,
                          size: 60),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _rating = 2.0;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.star,
                          color: _rating >= 2 ? Colors.purple : Colors.grey,
                          size: 60),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _rating = 3.0;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.star,
                          color: _rating >= 3 ? Colors.purple : Colors.grey,
                          size: 60),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _rating = 4.0;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.star,
                          color: _rating >= 4 ? Colors.purple : Colors.grey,
                          size: 60),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _rating = 5.0;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.star,
                          color: _rating >= 5 ? Colors.purple : Colors.grey,
                          size: 60),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText:
                      'Share details of your own experience about this place',
                ),
                maxLines: 4,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Center(
                child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: _getImages,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                  label: Text('Add photos'),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  children: _selectedPhotos
                      .map((photo) => _buildPhotoPreview(photo))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Center(
                  /* child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _postReview,
                  child: Text('Post review'),
                ),*/
                  ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I got this error,

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

when I'm accessing the reviewpage.dart. I don't know what's wrong because, when I'm accessing the placedetail.dart, the data pass along from welcome.dart. Then, when I want to access reviewpage.dart from the button 'Make a review' in placedetail.dart, it throw this error. I hope someone can help me solved this. Thanks in advance.

This error simply means you are providing null value where it is expecting value to be type string, before passing the value do check the value is null or not

Thank you sir for responding. I already solved the problem.

This error manifests when you're trying to assign a null value on a String variable.
So, for example, the following code would raise an error, since map doesn't contain an attribute called lastname:
Map<String, dynamic> map = {"firstname": "Ismah"};
String lastname = map['lastname'];

I can't be exactly sure where the error is thrown in your code without running it with your data, but from what you're saying I'd say the error is in placedetail.dart file:
You use a FutureBuilder and assign the snapshot data to var placeData = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;. Then later you try to push the ReviewPage using
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => ReviewPage(
      placeId: placeData['id'],
      placeName: placeData['placeName'],
    )), // Pass placeName to ReviewPage
);

If either of placeData['id'], placeData['placeName'] don't exist, the app will crash.
Generally though you should be defining Models that correspond to each of your firestore collection document structures and then be using DocumentSnapshot's get() method to retrieve the values. In this way if something like this goes wrong, you will at least be able to see the exact code line that the error is thrown.

Thanks for your response, sir. After I just recently posted the question, I finally understand the cause of the error. But in these codes, there is no mistake or misspell. I don't know after that, when I ask GPT, it just give me the same code as above, and it turn out well.
But, when I encounter this error again, I just realize that sometimes it's because of diff variable name. Let say in Firestore I save as namePlace, but i retrieved with placeName. This diff variable can cause this. Cause it detect the non-existed field data and that's why it returned null. Same like you explained.
